# C++ Make function call dependent on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Inside a C++ template function I would like to call another, overloaded function that has not yet been declared. Since the function is not dependent, the compiler will fail to resolve it.

The code looks like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
void serialize(const T &data)
{
    size_t data_size = getSize(data);
    std::cout << "Size: " << data_size << std::endl;
}

constexpr size_t getSize(const int &)
{
    return sizeof(int);
}

size_t getSize(const std::string &str)
{
    return str.size();
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t getSize(const std::array<T, N> &array)
{
    size_t array_size = 0;
    for (const T &element : array)
        array_size += getSize(element);
    return array_size;
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    serialize(a);

    std::string str = "foo";
    serialize(str);

    std::array<std::string, 2> arr = {{"foo", "foobar"}};
    serialize(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a nice way to make `getSize()` dependent? Or are there other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Declare `getSize()` as template function as well and specialize it for particular types.

Comment: How would you declare the templated `getSize()` for the array?

Comment: Actually you need a helper struct see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `getSize()` member of a helper struct:

```
template <typename T>
struct size_getter {
    static size_t getSize( T );
};

template <typename T>
void serialize(const T &data)
{
    size_t data_size = size_getter<T>::getSize( data );
    std::cout << "Size: " << data_size << std::endl;
}
```

then specialize them:

```
template<>
struct size_getter<std::string> {
    static size_t getSize( const std::string &s )
    {
        return s.size();
    }
};

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct size_getter<std::array<T, N>>
{
    static size_t getSize(const std::array<T, N> &array)
    {
        size_t array_size = 0;
        for (const T &element : array)
            array_size += size_getter<T>::getSize(element);
        return array_size;
    }
};
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/DAl54w)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a dummy tag to allow ADL:

```
template <typename T> struct tag {};

template <typename T>
void serialize(const T &data)
{
    size_t data_size = getSize(data, tag<T>{});
    std::cout << "Size: " << data_size << std::endl;
}

constexpr size_t getSize(const int &, tag<int>)
{
    return sizeof(int);
}

size_t getSize(const std::string &str, tag<std::string>)
{
    return str.size();
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t getSize(const std::array<T, N> &array, tag<std::array<T, N>>)
{
    size_t array_size = 0;
    for (const T &element : array)
        array_size += getSize(element, tag<T>{});
    return array_size;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcb8539959ffe4be)